# Would NServiceBus be the right choice for our app?

Tags: nservicebus, cqrs

I am currently working on a legacy app which does a lot of synchronous communication between machines. The communication is done largely by Http posts and I was wondering if we would benefit by using NServiceBus to make the communication asynchronous.

Through CQRS, I have become aware of NServiceBus but have not looked at it in detail.

Talking to colleagues who wrote the app, they see it as if the call cannot be made then the whole transaction fails and we should stick to this model. Most of the communication involves multiple users configuring hardware on the servers and maybe in this case we do not need some sort of queueing/async framework.

So what benefits would I have from going async and would NServiceBus be the right framework? How can I convince them that an asnyc messaging architecture is the way to go, if it is in our case? Or am I introducing a framework that is not necessary?

Comment: What happens when the POST fails?  What do you do to work around it?

Comment: Its all or nothing at this stage, so the whole transaction gets rolled back.

Comment: So I'll assume that the retry is manual.  If there is manual intervention and research is required prior to a retry, then I don't know if adding messaging would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the old maxim of "If it ain't broke".. comes into play here.

Seriously though, if there are no reasons to "fix" something (availability/data loss issues, for example) then it's very hard to build an argument for changing it.

To address your question a little, in my experience one of the main benefits of NServiceBus is low cost of ownership. It's easy to pick up, learn, deploy, and once in production has very little management overhead.

**UPDATE**

*RE: comment about displaying results of call to users:*

It depends on how you want to play it.

It is common in the CQRS pattern to display a success message to the user in this situation because it's very unlikely that by the time the user goes to check the results of the call that the result will be anything other than they expect.

However, if the call does some serious processing which could result in a delay, or if the call has a "naturally" high chance of failure then you could opt to display a "thanks for your request" message to the user and then alert them to the call outcome by some offline means (such as an email with a link to the response).

When you go async you have to start thinking about service level agreements in a different way - for example specifying that 99% of requests will be processed within 1 second, and then you can plan your design and infrastructure around that requirement.

Comment: Thanks, it was more trying to see if NServiceBus is necessary in our app and trying to get some feedback to see if there were any benefits.

Comment: NServiceBus would almost certainly meet all your requirements and give you a lot of benefit for free. One of the main benefits is that your code becomes a lot simpler as you can remove all the failure handling/compensation code as this is handled for you.

Comment: Thanks. If I did go with NServiceBus (ignoring the maxim for a mo), and something failed, would the user be left with a feeling that all worked even though my eventstore (I am using J Oliver's library for Event sourcing) has been updated but my calls to other machines have failed?